# return false in form submit

Tags: javascript, forms

I have function which runs on form submit. I notice that If I use return false even form is submitting. But if I remove the function which just before it then it is working fine. Why my `create` function causing problem or why form is submitting before complete execution. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tubmub2m/)

```
function abc(){
   create()     
return false;
}


function create(){
var myform = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[1];
if(myform.nextSibling.nodeName.indexOf('IMG')!=-1){
    myform.parentNode.removeChild(pixeldiv.nextSibling)
}
var id= Math.random().toString().split('.')[1];
var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML='adadfsa'
    insertAfter(img,myform)
}

function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected

```
var myform = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]//instead of [1]
...
insertAfter(div,myform)//instead of img
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tubmub2m/1/

Answer (score 0):

Because you have errors in your `create` function, that prevent returning false from `abc`.

In your fiddle `myform` and `img` are undefined that cause errors